# Can't limit upload speed

Tags: networking

I share a home network with my father and sister and in order to keep my father from being all grumpy when he gets high ping I need to limit my network bandwidth. I just recently switched to linux and I tried wondershaper and trickle.

When I used the command

```
sudo wondershaper [interface] 4000 160
```

My download speed at least seemed to be limited but upload went to 50 KB/s which is basically all of my network’s upload power. I also used trickle like this:

```
sudo trickled -d 500 -u 20
```

And again the same thing happened. I used nload and bmon to monitor network speeds. Only have one interface.